# How do you put image/texture on part of a geometry in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have created a simple sphere in three.js using `SphereGeometry` and `MeshPhongMaterial` to give it a static color. I am wondering how I can overlay an image that only takes up a small portion of the sphere. I am aware of ways to wrap an entire texture around an object, but not how to just put it in one spot.

Comment: You can change uv coordinates of sphere's geometry or write your own custom shader.

Comment: Are they any examples of this online? I could not find any.

Comment: Apart from @prisoner849's suggestions, you can also design your sphere in a DCC tool like Blender, export it as `glTF` and load it via `THREE.GLTFLoader`. I've often read similar question in the past and many users struggle with modifying texture coordinates or writing custom shader code. It's more straightforward to design an asset like your sphere in a tool and then just import and render it.

Comment: Or you can use `THREE.DecalGeometry`. [example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals)

Comment: @vHawk you should post your comment as an answer – I had the same question as OP and `THREE.DecalGeometry` seems to be just what I needed!

Comment: @fredrikekelund Done. I'm glad it was useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `THREE.DecalGeometry`, which allows to project textures/images onto any `THREE.Mesh`.

[Example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals)